# python launcher won't launch .py files

Tags: python, file, nameerror

I just made a python script on my MacBook, named moodplayer.py.
Now I'd like to run that file with the python launcher. I follow the usual steps: I open the python launcher and click File -> open recent -> moodplayer.py on top of the screen. When I do this, nothing happens. There is only a second window that appears and disappears in a millisecond.
I tried to run it from the terminal, but nothing happens there either.

The code:

```
from playsound import playsound
import sqlite3
import tkinter as tk
a = sqlite3.connect("hassan.db")
b = a.cursor()
def mood():
    c = b.execute("select song from moodplayer where mood = '{}'".format(boi.get()))
    d = c.fetchall()
    e = str(d).strip("[(')],")
    playsound("{}".format(e))

yos = "welcome to the moodplayer, an exclusive mp3 player that plays songs dependent on your mood. How are you feeling right now?"


root = tk.Tk()
yeet = tk.Label(root, text=yos)
yeet.pack()
boi = tk.Entry(root, bg="blue")
boi.pack()
kaas = tk.Button(root, text="speel af", command=mood)
kaas.pack()
```

Another weird problem is when I try to run any other .py file from the terminal, I get this error message:

```
Amirs-MacBook-Air:Desktop Amirmousawi$ python3 reken.py
  File "reken.py", line 1
    book
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Here's the code from the reken.py file:

```
a = input()
b = input()
print(a + b)
```

The same happens with every other .py file.

Does anybody know a solution? It would be appreciated!

Comment: When you say "Python launcher", do you mean `IDLE` (the Python in-built IDE)? Also, try adding `root.mainloop()` to the end of your code.

Comment: I mean the actual python launcher, the program that's used to run python files

Comment: Does `root.mainloop()` work, though? Also, the behaviour with the "book error" is very odd and I cannot find that behaviour anywhere with a quick Google.

Comment: I inserted that in my code, and tried to run it again. It still doesn't do anything. I only see the mouse cursor showing the loading sign for a long time until the launcher simply closes.

Comment: It does work now when I launch it from the terminal, but not when I launch it from the python launcher.